# export indexDB throws error "storeNames parameter was empty"

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, dexie

can anyone please help me out, I'm new to Dexie (Angular)

```
import Dexie from 'dexie';
import {ExportOptions, exportDB} from 'dexie-export-import';

const db = await new Dexie('myDB');
const blob = await exportDB(db);
```

I'm using exportDB method to export the indexDB with angular,
but it gives me error like

```
InvalidAccessError: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': The storeNames parameter was empty.
```

Instead of exportDB function I have also tried like

```
const blob = await db.export(options);
```

But it throws error like `TypeError: db.export is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call `open` on the database constructor:

```
import Dexie from 'dexie';
import { ExportOptions, exportDB } from 'dexie-export-import';

const exportDatabase = async (dbName) => { 
    const db = await new Dexie(dbName).open();
    const blob = await exportDB(db);
    return blob;
}
```